# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with Java Vector.addElement(Object o) method

Tags: java, vector, out-of-memory

Although I know usage of Java Vectors is discouraged as its deprecated, I am stuck with a legacy code where in I don't have the luxury to modify it.

I am getting an OutOfMemoryError while trying to addElement to the Vector. Following below is my code snippet. Please let me know if I can improve the below code.

```
 /*objOut is the Vector Object.
     idx is incoming integer argument. 
     Val is some Object
   */
    int sz = objOut.size();
                    if (idx == sz) {
                        objOut.addElement(val);
                    } else if (idx > sz) {
                        for (int i = (idx-sz); i>0; i--) {
                            objOut.addElement(null); // Code through OutOfMemory in this line
                        }
                        objOut.addElement(val);
                    } else {
                        objOut.setElementAt(val, idx);
                    }
```

Comment: that is hardly enough context, you dont get outofmemory from one addElement call. Give us more context or knowledge. Is it performed in a loop? If yes, when does the loop abort? etc...

Comment: Increase JVM heap space with -Xmx, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/37335/1140748

Comment: You are trying to add a lot of items. When the OutOfMemoryError occured means it need more heap memory, increase the heap space it may resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In your program, you are trying to allocate `n` number of objects.
Your OS allocates some space to your JVM to work with and that space is called `heap space`. You get `OutOfMemoryError` when all of your heap space is filled and no more space is left to allocate for new objects.

So what you should do is increase your heap space with `-Xmx` like this:

```
java -Xmx 1024m YourClassName
```

This will allocate a heap space of 1024 MB's (1 GB) for your program. You may request for heap space as per your requirement.